# CSS/LESS allow content to grow while keeping div centered vertically

Tags: css, less

I have a banner that ends with a triangle(arrow) that has to stay centered vertically overlapping the slideshow below it. The amount of text/content that it will accept can grow dynamically. Is there a way to style this so that as the text increases the arrow will stay centered as you see below. Below is the styling that I have to achieve the screenshot below.

```
.carousel {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:3.5em;
    padding-bottom:5%;

    .header {
        position: absolute;
        top:-2em;
        left:0;
        z-index: 1000;
        background-color:#81C3C4;
        color:white;
        font-family:Lato;
    }

    .headerWithTag {
        position: absolute;
        top:-3.5em;
        left:0;
        z-index: 1000;
        background-color:#81C3C4;
        color:white;
        font-family:Lato;

        &:after {
            content: "";
            background: url(/img/styleguide/masterslider/h1_right_top.svg) no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

React Component HTML:

{headerClass} = either .header or .headerWithTag depending if there is a subtitle(h3 tag).

```
<div className="carousel">
    <div className={headerClass}>
        <h1>{headerText}</h1>
        <h3>{this.props.subTitle}</h3>
    </div>
    <div className="slideShow">
        <div>
            <div ref="wrapper" className="master-slider ms-skin-default" data-qa={thisName + '_masterslider'}>
                {slides}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the html as well?

Comment: @AvAvt That is basically the HTML it all gets rendered dynamically because it is a reactjs componet

Comment: So you want the arrow to point at the horizontal center of the slideShow, and when more texts are added the header will expand to the left?

Comment: The point of the arrow has to always stay where it is in the screenshot. The height and width need to scale base on the amount of content/text passed into it. BTW thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm still quite hard to imagine without a jsfiddle to tinker on, but would removing `left: 0;` and replacing it with `right: 50%;` fit your description?

Comment: Yes that would except my brain is fried and i wrote horizontally instead of vertically in my question. I apologize. It need to hug the left and then expand to the right with more text and stay vertically centered with the arrow where it is in the screen shot. Sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97319/discussion-between-jackncoke-and-av-avt).

Comment: Ooh. Remove `top: -2em;` or 3.5em and use `top: 0; transform: translate(0, -50%);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution is to use `top:0; transform: translate(0, -50%)` to shift the header up half its height from the top of the slide:

```
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    left:0;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color:#81C3C4;
    color:white;
    font-family:Lato;
  }

  .headerWithTag {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    left:0;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color:#81C3C4;
    color:white;
    font-family:Lato;

    &:after{
      content: "";
      background: url(/img/styleguide/masterslider/h1_right_top.svg) no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;

    }
  }
```

Quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7ky4wvz6/1/

Comment: Just a little specification. This solution works great only in last browsers. IE8 completely lacks support for "_CSS transformations_", while IE9 requires ad hoc syntax (please see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) )